# Django Query Result Is NoneType?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I have this query that looks like this:

```
blah = Blah.objects.filter(foo=title)
```

It works fine, so I can use the results in a template. BUT, I need to change one of the values in it, from an integer to a timedelta so it will display a time in the template output. Having trouble doing this, I wondered why type the result is & discovered that, `type(blah)`, tells me that it's a NoneType, even tho it actually has usuable values. That's very puzzling, and I couldn't find anything in the Django documentation about this.

I tried using `blah['length']`, to get my specific integer, but that didn't work. So it appears the type isn't a dict, set, or list.

**So, what type is a Django query result and why does it tell me it's a NoneType even tho it isn't?**

I'm really scratching my head on this one.

Comment: `blah` in the above example should never be `None`, it may return an empty `django.db.models.query.QuerySet` if no results are found.  Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: That'd be weird if the problem is elsewhere, 'cause the code works fine unless I attempt to use the result object in some way before I use it in the template. I guess I have some trial & error ahead of me tonight. sigh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django querysets are of their own type. The idea for them is to retrieve sets of objects and for that they provide Django's public queryset API ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/)). As a result of that, it's probably not a good idea to change any queryset attributes since there is no guarantee future Django releases will have the same attributes. You can however change attributes of model instances they return:

```
qs = FooModel.objects.all()
for model in qs:
    model.attr = 'foo'
```

So in your case you can do something like:

```
# assuming you allow your integer field to be null
class FooModel(models.Model):
    time = models.IntegerField(null=True)

qs = FooModel.objects.all()
for model in qs:
    # handle case when time is null - model.time will be None
    t = model.time or 90
    model.time = timedelta(seconds=t)
```

If however you only need to retreive one object (model instance), then you should probably use `get` queryset method instead of `filter`:

```
foo = FooModel.objects.get(...)
foo.time = timedelta(seconds=foo.time)
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the querysets, I hadn't found that page yet. I was lookin' in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/. I tried the code you suggested, and even used int(), but Django still throws an error - "int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'".

Comment: That exception is not raised by Django. That means that you are passing to `int` not a number it can convert. You have to make sure whatever you are passing is a valid number.

Comment: The value of `model.time` in this case is 248 in the database, so handling for `None` isn't neccessary. Thanks tho.

Comment: Tried the code anyway, and it worked. Weird! Thanks! Now, I think it was processing some that were `None`, before it got to the one that I thought I was processing.